# Is there way to run a file with instruction in the erlang shell?

Tags: erlang

I have a file .erlang in the current dir I run erl shell that compiles a few modules.

Is there way to re run this file from the Erlang shell.

I run erl I get the shell 1> and from there run like run_file(".erlang") and this file execute the instructions in the current shell and load the env.

The file looks like

```
compile:file(file1). 
compile:file(file2).
compile:file(file3).
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`file:eval/1`](http://erldocs.com/R14B02/kernel/file.html?i=26&search=eval#eval/1).

Given a `.erlang` with this content:

```
io:format("Hello world!~n").
```

You get:

```
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1> file:eval(".erlang").
Hello, world!
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [escript](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html).

Comment: I mean, from the erlang shell. I run erl i get the shell 1> and from there run like run_file(".erlang") and this file execute the instructions in the current shell and load the env.. Thanks!

Comment: If it's the first thing you want to do, you can pass `erl` the `-eval` flag. Otherwise you could use [`eval`](http://www.trapexit.org/String_Eval) on the contents of the file.